# Why does Files.isHidden(Path) return false for directories on Windows?

Tags: java, windows, nio, hidden-files

From the documentation of [`Files.isHidden(Path)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#isHidden(java.nio.file.Path)) (**emphasis** mine):

> Tells whether or not a file is considered *hidden*. The exact definition of hidden is platform or provider dependent. On UNIX for example a file is considered to be hidden if its name begins with a period character ('.'). **On Windows a file is considered hidden if it isn't a directory and the DOS hidden attribute is set.**
>
> Depending on the implementation this method may require to access the file system to determine if the file is considered hidden.

From this I can understand *what* the expected behavior is. However, *why* is this the expected behavior?

The reason I'm wondering is because of the difference in behavior between `Files.isHidden`, `DosFileAttributes.isHidden`, and Windows' *File Explorer*. For instance, I can go into *File Explorer* and set a directory to be hidden and it will no longer show up (unless I configure it to show hidden items). If I test if said directory is hidden with Java then `Files.isHidden` returns `false` and `DosFileAttributes.isHidden` returns `true`. You can test this with the following code:

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.attribute.DosFileAttributes;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {  
    final var directory = Path.of(args[0]).toAbsolutePath().normalize();
    final var store     = Files.getFileStore(directory);
    final var dosAttrs  = Files.readAttributes(directory, DosFileAttributes.class);

    System.out.println("Directory     : " + directory);
    System.out.println("FileStore     : " + store.name() + " [" + store.type() + "]");
    System.out.println("Hidden (Files): " + Files.isHidden(directory));
    System.out.println("Hidden (Dos)  : " + dosAttrs.isHidden());
  }

}
```

---

*Note: I'm using Windows 10 and OpenJDK 11.0.1. My file system is NTFS*.

---

Running this with:

```
java Main.java C:\path\to\hidden\directory
```

I get:

```
Directory     : C:\path\to\hidden\directory
FileStore     : OS [NTFS]
Hidden (Files): false
Hidden (Dos)  : true
```

---

*Note: This behavior appears to be part of `WindowsFileSystemProvider`. The method `Files.isHidden(Path)` simply forwards the call to the argument's `FileSystem`'s provider. The implementation is basically:*

```java
DosFileAttributes attrs = ...; // get attributes
return !attrs.isDirectory() && attrs.isHidden();
```

---

I found this [(non)-issue](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8170334) (JDK-8170334) where a comment says:

> I don't think we have a bug here because the hidden attribute is meaningless on directories.

Yet *File Explorer*, which is core software on Windows, behaves like the hidden attribute is *not* meaningless on directories. So again, why does the Java implementation on Windows take into account whether or not the `Path` points to a directory? Or is Java correct and *File Explorer* is doing non-standard things?

I'm inclined to think *File Explorer* is correct because both *CMD* (via `dir`) and *PowerShell* (via `Get-ChildItem`) won't list hidden directories either; not unless the appropriate options are specified.

Comment: I'm not a Java dev, and I'm not going to delve into JDK design issues, but on its surface this looks to me like someone is confusing the hidden and readonly attributes. Setting the readonly attribute on a directory is ignored by the Windows shell (Explorer) because it's not useful. All it does is prevent deleting an empty directory. In contrast, setting the immutable attribute on a directory in Linux/BSD (via chattr / chflags, typically as the super user) prevents modifying the directory in any way.

Comment: Beware when using dosAttrs.isHidden() on my box "C:\" returns True

Comment: @Stig Same here (Java 12.0.1, Windows 10). However, PowerShell also says `"C:\"` is hidden, so this is probably expected behavior.

Comment: I agree it is not a bug but it would surprise most.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I checked [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/file-attribute-constants) for file attributes provided by Microsoft for Windows platform. It says that if attribute `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN = 2 (0x2)` is set

> The file or directory is hidden. It is not included in an ordinary directory listing.

As I can see in the class `sun.nio.fs.WindowsConstants` there is the same value definition used by DosFileAttributes.isHidden() method - `public static final int FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN = 0x00000002;` which for my understanding should be mapped one to one with the attribute available for Windows, so in general `hidden` flag for a directory should be working in the same way as for a regular file. 
In relation to operating system/file system integration, this behaviour seems to be incorrect.

Comment: Rectifying the `Files.isHidden()` bug will break existing Windows Java applications that dutifully follow its buggy definition for a hidden directory on Windows system that don't further check with `DosFileAttributes.isHidden()`. It is probably why Java API devs don't want to make it an issue since we can still use `DosFileAttributes.isHidden()` to make up the correct behavior.

Comment: I ended up submitting a bug report: [JDK-8215467](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8215467). We'll see where that goes but @ecle may be right and it won't be fixed for reasons explained in their comment; that's if it's not closed as "not an issue" as two other bug reports were.

Comment: Turns out it was a bug after all. Report says it's fixed in Java 13.